# I can't find my address from MEW when i want to connect my ledger nano s

Tags: myetherwallet, ledger-nano-s

I have been holding for 6 or 7 months now and when I went to check myetherwallet today, I was unable to find my wallets with all my ETH and my ERC-20 tokens. I plugged in my ledger like I always did, and connected it to MEW, but the addresses I'm used to seeing are no longer there. I scroll through the list of addresses but can't find them.

I have my addresses written down, and when I check them I can see my coins in there, but like I said I am unable to find the address on MEW when I plug in my ledger nano s. Is there a way to manually search for my address or something?

Anyone else having this issue? I'm guessing it has something to do with Ledger Nano S updates or MEW updates, but I can't figure this out and it's super scary, because I'm afraid I won't be able to get my tokens out of those addresses.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should export the private keys of the individual wallets on MEW.

Comment: Are there any resources that could help me figure out how to do that. Thank you so much for your reply by the way. I truly appreciate the help.

Comment: I have the same problem with my trezor. were you able to find the address?